# VMware vmplayer failing to launch VM on Ubuntu: "Could not open /dev/vmmon"

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vmware-player

I get the following error when trying to launch an ova VM using VMPlayer on Ubuntu 12.04

```
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory. Please make sure the kernel module 'vmmon' is loaded
```

I checked with lsmod and it was indeed not loaded. When i try to load the module using "modprobe -v vmmon", i get the following error:-

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/misc/vmmon.ko
FATAL: Error inserting vmmon (/lib/modules/3.5.0-37-generic/misc/vmmon.ko): Invalid module format
```

Then I found from the VMware forums the following suggestion:-

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/vmware/modules/binary /usr/lib/vmware/modules/binary.old 
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all --appname="VMware Player" --icon="vmware-player"
```

This does a lot of compilation, which I guess is to compile the module again, but I get the following output at the end of it:-

```
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                            failed
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Blocking file system                                                done
   Virtual ethernet                                                    done
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
Unable to start services
```

After this I get the same error as the start of the whole process. This has got me completely stumped for 2 days now, any help will be highly appreciated :(

Answer (score 0):

uninstall it as root, and reinstall. this will likely fix the issue for you.

Comment: No, didn't work. Same errors.